# Interfaces as return types with JAX-WS + JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I think I'm just missing something simple here but here is what I am working from...

```
@WebService
public interface MyService {
     public AnInterface doStuff();
}
```

Here is some of what I have tried. All with CXF 2.5.2 + Spring on Weblogic 10.3.4...

1. Use @XmlSeeAlso on the MyService interface and AnInterface to point JAXB to the `AnInterfaceImpl` class. This still resulted in the infamous JAXB can't handle interfaces exception.
2. Used @XmlElementReference on the method but this had the same effect as item (1) and seems to be for property serialization
3. Use @ResponseWrapper on the method but it's my understanding that CXF does this automatically (Bare vs Wrapped) but I may be wrong. While this allowed WSDL to be created marshaling at runtime always returned a default object. Perhaps I misunderstand how this annotation should work.

I'm guessing there is some way to easily annotate that `AnInterface` should be exposed via
 `AnInterfaceImpl` from the `MyService` class pretty easily but I'm missing some crucial and simple step.

Comment: What happens if you were to add `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})`?  I think CXF defaults to `*/*` so that it may matter what the client is sending in accepts header.

Comment: @unhillbilly: I think you are confusing JAX-RS with JAX-WS. In JAX-WS it's always XML. Correct me if I'm wrong, I am new.

Comment: You are spot on. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick appears to be the use of [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) on the target interfaces as described [here](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html#Use__XmlJavaTypeAdapter). It is not obvious to me why this works where other methods seem to fail.